# how to C# stream video (images) to HTML5 client?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, client, buffer

I am using C# to receive continuous bitmaps (video) from an ipcamera. Then I am converting them to base64string and sending (JSON) to HTML5 canvas. Canvas is rendering the images.

While searching I found how to send images from C# to HTML5 and render them on canvas.

My question is how to **buffer** the received images from IpCamera and send to HTML5 (multiple) clients in background?

any suggestions. 
Can I create mpeg stream in C# app? then how to read the mpeg from html5?
Is there any thing like stream reader on HTML5 side?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to stream bitmaps from server (written in C#) to many clients (in JS/HTML5). 
SignalR has hubs that can be used to stream to a group of clients (e.g. see [SignalR Hubs Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr.htm))